# "ReadKey" Error - suddenly appears working on powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have the following script which until now worked just fine.

```
# Mailbox Migration Script
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010;

#$UserCredential = Get-Credential -Message "`n Please supply your O365 credentials using (Example: user@corp.mycorp.com): `n "
#$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection


#Import-PSSession $Session

#Choose, USERNAME related to mailbox:
Write-Host "`n ATTENTION : THIS SCRIPT WILL SHUT DOWN IF YOU ENTER WRONG MAILBOX INFO `n OR THE MAILBOX HAS ALREADY BEEN MIGRATED." -for Red;  
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "`n Please provide AD-USERNAME to Migrate";
Write-Host "`n The chosen user is:";
Write-Host "`n " $username -for Yellow;
Write-Host "`n Press ENTER key to confirm and continue. `n Press CTRL+C to cancel";
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
```

Now after running this, i get an error which crashes the script.

```
Exception calling "ReadKey" with "1" argument(s): "The method or operation is not 
implemented."
At C:\Users\username\Desktop\PowerShell\Migration-prompt.ps1:19 char:1
+ $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordExcepti 
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotImplementedException
```

I imagine the issue should be somewhere on this line:

```
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
```

Your help would be mostly appreciated on fixing this.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the troubled line with this one.

```
$null = Read-Host
```

If you want to troubleshoot the issue instead, start with the error. *The method is not implemented*. The PowerShell host has changed in some fashion. What is the output for `$host`?